# Java/Spring - Set Attribute in HttpRequest and Override Previous Value

Tags: java, spring, httprequest

I want to override value which parameter gets via post method. But I get previous value of "from" which is posted.

```
@Override
public void handle(Map<String, Object> map, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {
    if (request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("POST")) {
        request.setAttribute("from", "IST");
    }
}
```

Comment: You should update your request to ExternalContext, like FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().setRequest(request);

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50544954/2471528